# how to align elements at end in HorizontalStackLayout ( maui )?

Tags: xaml, maui

I trying to put two buttons inside the of HorizontalStackLayout by using "HorizontalOptions='End'" but it didn't work here is the code and the result as a picture:

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout Padding="30">
    <Label 
        Text="History"
        VerticalOptions="Start" 
        HorizontalOptions="Start" />
    <Border>
        <HorizontalStackLayout BackgroundColor="Black">
            <Border>
                <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" MaximumWidthRequest="500" TextColor="White" MaximumHeightRequest="60" Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry" />
            </Border>
            <Button BackgroundColor="Wheat" TextColor="Black" Text="Send" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
            <Button BackgroundColor="Wheat" TextColor="Black" Text="Delete" HorizontalOptions="End"/>    
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Border>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Try to set 'HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" for the first button

Comment: @AndreaGobs, IIRC, that won't force the stacklayout to expand, unless stacklayout is also told to "Fill".

Comment: Yes true @ToolmakerSteve

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/horizontalstacklayout#position-and-size-child-views):

> A HorizontalStackLayout only respects the alignment preferences on
> child views that are in the opposite direction to the orientation of
> the layout.

Instead you can try using FlexLayout:

```
<VerticalStackLayout Padding="30">
<Label 
    Text="History" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
<Border>
    <FlexLayout Direction="Row" BackgroundColor="Black">
        <Label FlexLayout.Grow="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" MaximumWidthRequest="500" TextColor="White" MaximumHeightRequest="60" Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry" />
        <Button  BackgroundColor="Wheat" TextColor="Black" Text="Send"/>
        <Button  BackgroundColor="Wheat" TextColor="Black" Text="Delete"/>
    </FlexLayout>
</Border>
```

[image: Screenshot of result]

Comment: or a Grid with `Grid.ColumnDefinitions="*,auto,auto"` or something with fixed widths for the buttons like `Grid.ColumnDefinitions="*,40,40"` (for better layout performance)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to create a parent element Grit with columns definition = "N,Auto,N" (N just a number you can pick it) , with this solution there is no space after the buttons .

Comment: Please use code fences when providing code examples. Some options here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I'm surprised `Auto` worked to use up the space. The usual solution is to have `*` for the column that receives all the remaining space. Also, this answer would be greatly improved if you **showed the complete code of the Grid element, and which elements it encloses,** instead of describing what you did. This removes ambiguity. Does it wrap the buttons? The HorizontalStackLayout? Are the buttons in separate columns? Code is best.